# Regex indentation - keep tabs at beginning of line

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using regular expressions in C#. I'd like to move a match to a new line and indent. By indenting, I mean that pre-existing tabs should be kept and added to, that existed at the beginning of the line containing the match.

**What is the best way to do this with one regex match and replacement?**

For example, matching a word following a comma:

```
W 1, 2, 3
    W 4, 5, 6
        W 7, 8, 9
```

Should lead to:

```
W 1,
    2,
    3
    W 4,
        5,
        6
        W 7,
            8,
            9
```

I can match with `(?<=,)`, and simply replace with `\n` or even `\n\t`. However, with this method, the indentation is reset for each match to one tab, and doesn't follow the pre-existing indentation.

I've also tried working with named groups, such as looking at existing indentation through `(?<tabs>^\t+|\n\t+)`, and matches to be indented through `(?<words>(?<=,))`. However, I can't figure out how to combine this into one match and one replace regex pattern.

Comment: Why the downvote and close vote?

Comment: Does it have to be done with regular expressions?

Comment: Using your rule, I don't understand why "5," is indented more than "W 4,"

Comment: @BradThomas sorry the rule wasn't more precise. I should say the matching rule is: any character 0 or more times following a comma, including the first next comma, newline, or end of file. In the example, 5 is indented more than 4 because a newline, indentation (increased by one tab), and then the match itself, should replace each match. Although the example is in reality one string, the indentation happens on a per-line basis.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I've come up with.  It doesn't use any regular expressions because **this problem doesn't need to use them**.  You can decide for yourself if this works for you :)

[Working dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qjk8CH)

```
var input =
@"W 1, 2, 3
    W 4, 5, 6
        W 7, 8, 9";

var output = string.Empty;
var inputLines = input.Split('\n');

foreach(var inputLine in inputLines) {
    // get leading whitespace for line... you can use Regex here to match
    // more WS characters if you'd like
    var leadingWsAmt = inputLine.Length - inputLine.TrimStart(' ').Length;
    var leadingWs = new string(' ', leadingWsAmt);

    // trim all strings separated by comma so whitespace is correct in final result
    var inputsOnLine = inputLine
        .Split(',')
        .Select(x => x.Trim());

    output += string.Join(",\n"+leadingWs+"\t", inputsOnLine);

    // don't put comma after last item
    output += "\n"+leadingWs+"\t";
}
output = output.Trim();

Console.WriteLine(output);
// W 1,
//     2,
//     3
//     W 4,
//         5,
//         6
//         W 7,
//             8,
//             9
```